# Posting data from Java and receiving in node.js applicaiton

Tags: java, node.js, post

I have written a demo in Java that posts data once a second:

```
public static void main(String[] arystrArgs) {
    //Get Operating System name and version     
    String strOSname = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    //Display application title and what it is running on       
    System.out.println("Java Data Posting Demo");
    System.out.println("Build date: " + BUILD_DATE + ", Version: " + VERSION_NO);
    System.out.println("Running on: " + strOSname.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() 
                                      + strOSname.substring(1).toLowerCase());
    //Post data to server
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;

    while( true ) {
        try {
                Thread.sleep(DELAY_BETWEEN_POSTS);

                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                if ( conn != null ) {
                    //Whatever you wants to post...                 
                    String strPostData = "p1=Hello&p2=" + (new Date()).getTime();

                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString(strPostData.length()));
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-GB");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);

                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes(strPostData);
                    dos.close();

                    System.out.println("Post to: " + url.toString() + ", data: " + strPostData);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException|IOException ex) {
                    //ex.printStackTrace();                 
            } finally {
                if ( conn != null ) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                    conn = null;
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

I have written a Node.js application that listens on port 8080, but I don't see any POST requests in the http handler, I only see GET requests when I use a browser on the same address and port to test.

Snippet from node.js application:

```
function defaultHandler(request, response) {
    try{
           if ( request.method == "POST" ) {
               var strBody = "";
               request.on("data", function(chunk) {
                   strBody += chunk;
               });

               request.on("end", function() {
                   console.log("Received posted data: " + strBody);
               });
           } else {
                      console.dir(request);
                  }
      } catch( ex ) {
          console.dir(ex);
      }
};

var app = http.createServer(defaultHandler);
app.listen(8080);
```

This is a cut down version, but all I ever see is get requests. I can see that the Java is connecting and posting data, as when I start Node.js and only when I start Node.js, the Java application connects to the URL then starts POSTING with a second delay between posts, it I terminate node, then it stops posting and restarting node causes the posts to resume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, it was the Java, I modified the Java code as follows:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

    if ( conn != null ) {
    //Whatever you wants to post...                 
            String strPostData = "p1=Hello&p2=" + (new Date()).getTime();

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en;q=0.5");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", Integer.toString(strPostData.length()));
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-GB");
            conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(strPostData);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            int intResponse = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' to " + url.toString() + 
                    ", data: " + strPostData + ", rc: " + intResponse);;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Node app never send response to client. You send a lot of request but Java Client never receive response from server. You should execute end method on response.

```
var http = require('http');

function defaultHandler(request, response) {
    try {
        if (request.method == "POST") {
            var strBody = "";
            request.on("data", function(chunk) {
                strBody += chunk;
            });
            request.on("end", function() {
                console.log("Received posted data: " + strBody);
            });
        } else {
            console.dir(request);
        }

        respone.end(); // for example here

    } catch (ex) {
        console.dir(ex);
    }
};

var app = http.createServer(defaultHandler);
app.listen(8080);
```

Here you can find documentation - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

I'm not a Java developer, but I think you can try use flush and getResponseCode method on connection.

```
conn.setDoOutput(true);

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
dos.writeBytes(strPostData);
dos.flush();
dos.close();

int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: I will try adding the response.end() to the node.js code, but as far as the Java is concernt I tried flushing and closing with no change.

Comment: I tried adding a console message when node.js receives a POST request, but it never displays the message indicating that node.js isn't receiving a POST request.

Comment: Are you sure Java sends a request?

Comment: I checked your Node code with Postman (send request) and this code is working.

Comment: Thank you, I will try directing the Java to post to a conventional web-server.

Comment: If my answer / comments was helpful, please up vote :) Thanks :)

Comment: When I launch the Java applicaiton it displays the initial start-up message then once I start the node.js application is begins to post the data to the URL http://localhost:8080, as far as I can see it is doing what it should do, but node.js doesn't appear to be getting the POST.

Comment: hmmmm.....I modified the default document that node.js serves up and added a HTML form using the POST method, and this works, node.js receives the posted data and displays the message on the console....so Java isn't posting the data...why?

Comment: I wrote you about that Node is working properly and problem is with Java... But I'm not a Java Developer and I can help you only with Node